# unter anderem gehören

Tags: meaning

Wieso schreibt man so oft "unter anderem" wenn man das Verb *gehören* verwendet und welche Bedeutung hat das?

> Zu seinen Aufgaben gehört unter anderem die Prüfung der Rechnungslegung des Unternehmens...

Comment: Ich befürchte, dass es den Zusammenhang zwischen "unter anderem" und "gehören" so nicht gibt.

Comment: @tofro Das muss nicht falsch sein. Es kommt auf den Kontext drauf an und den hat man unter Umständen mit nur diesem Satz noch nicht. Z.b. irgenwelche Gruppenzugehörigkeiten aus der Sicht von Niclas Füllkrug

Comment: Ich hoffe, mit dem neuen Beispiel wird die Frage wird die Frage besser verdeutlicht.

Comment: Besser, ja. ----

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An sich gibt es keinen Zusammenhang zwischen "unter andere[mn]" und spezifisch dem Verb "gehören". Dein Beispiel lässt sich mit vielen anderen Verben genauso ausdrücken:

> Seine Aufgaben sind unter anderem ...
>
> Seine Aufgaben bestehen unter anderem in ...
>
> Seine Aufgaben umfassen unter anderem ...
>
> Seine Aufgaben beinhalten unter anderem ...

Also alles, was die *Zugehörigkeit zu einer Gruppe* ausdrücken kann.

Den gleichen Sachverhalt kann man statt "unter anderem" (das explizit sagt, dass es noch mehr gibt) auch mit "zum Beispiel" (was nur *impliziert*, dass es noch andere geben könnte) praktisch deckungsgleich ausdrücken.

Dein ursprünglicher Beispielsatz

> Der Fußballer Niclas Füllkrug gehört unter andere**m** zu seinen Schützlingen.

würde übrigens möglicherweise fehlgedeutet werden (ich denke mal, das Beispiel soll sagen, dass es auch noch andere Schützlinge gibt) als

> ...gehört unter andere**m** zu seinen Schützlingen. Er gehört aber auch zu seinen Kreditgebern und zu seinen ärgsten Feinden

Wollte man das ausdrücken, was ich oben angenommen habe, sollte man schreiben

> ...gehört unter andere**n** zu seinen Schützlingen. Fritz Müller und Franz Maier gehören auch dazu.

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt keinen direkten, grammatikalischen Zusammenhang zwischen "gehören" und "unter anderem".

Ganz zufällig ist es allerdings nicht, dass die beiden Ausdrücke häufiger mal zusammen vorkommen: Den meisten Menschen "gehört" ziemlich viel, materiell wie immateriell. Ihr Geld, ihre Kleidung, ihre Überzeugungen, ihre Angewohnheiten, der Kaugummi unter ihrem Schuh ... und unter anderem auch ihre Aufgaben. Hoppla, da wars schon wieder, dieses "unter anderem". Es dient in diesem Zusammenhang der Kennzeichnung, dass ich mir bewusst bin, dass einem Menschen mehr gehört, als ich gerade aufgezählt habe. Die Aufgaben sind ein Stichpunkt *unter vielen anderen*.

Zum Beispiel ist es oft so, dass ein Mensch mehr als nur eine einzige Aufgabe hat. Wenn ich die nicht alle aufzählen möchte (weil ich speziell etwas zur Prüfung der Rechnungslegung des Unternehmens sagen will und der Rest gerade irrelevant ist), dann kann ich mit einem "unter anderem" zu erkennen geben, dass mir deren Fülle sehr wohl bewusst ist.

Natürlich könnte man auch sagen:

> Zu seinen Aufgaben gehört die Prüfung der Rechnungslegung des Unternehmens...

..und das wäre nicht falsch. Nur eben ohne die Betonung, dass es noch mehrere andere, aktuell aber irrelevante Aufgaben gibt.

Comment: Prinzipiell einig, allerdings verstehe ich nicht, was mir der zweite Absatz sagen soll: "Etwas gehört *jemandem*" (in deiner Antwort) und "Etwas gehört *zu etwas*" (wie in der Frage) sind zwei grundverschiedene Aussagen.

Comment: @tofro Meine Antwort bezieht sich allgemein auf die Kombination von "gehören" und "unter anderem", nicht nur auf den Beispielfall. Ich würde vermuten, dass "etwas gehört jemandem" mindestens so oft auftritt wie "etwas gehört zu etwas" - und in beiden Fällen hat das kombinierte Auftreten denselben Hintergrund.

Comment: Oder anders gesagt: "etwas gehört jemandem" gehört unter anderem auch zu den Kombinationsmöglichkeiten mit "unter anderem" ;)